# PaddleOCR for Tajik Language

Tags: paddleocr

Tajik language uses cyrillic, do I have to create new model from scratch or fine tune Russian cyrillic model?

Tajik has extra letters ӣ, ҳ, қ, ҷ, ӯ, ғ

Tajik and the Russian language are different